# Miscoloured lines in rule-based layer styling in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm styling a vector layer of roads and have noticed that a small subset of lines appear to be going 'rogue' and ignoring their line colour styling. They still obey the line stroke and width style however but insist on being yellow instead of the desired colour.

I've added a separate rule for one of them and it definitely 'catches' the correct line segment and restyles it in every way EXCEPT for the colour which stubbornly remains yellow.

Can anyone provide me with any clues as to what is going on here?

[image: Example of rogue yellow road segment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line (or lines) are "selected" - You have one of the selection tools active and have clicked on the line. See the [manual for more details](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#select-and-deselect-features), you need to click on the clear selection tool

[image: the clear selection tool]

to remove it.

Comment: What an idiot I am. Thank you though. I was going out of my mind to figure what the styling override might be.